# Got undefined from the CORS API call in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cors, frontend, backend

I am trying to call a REST API hosted locally using CORS, and fetch the data to visualize on my front-end wrote using React. But I keep getting undefined from the data fetch function, and the function works well when I console out the data in the 'onload' handler. Here are my two scripts doing data fetching:

```js
// App.js
import {fetchIntradayDataHR, fetchDailyLogHR} from './DataFetch';

// ...
  componentWillMount() {
    // Called the first time when the component is loaded right before the component is added to the page
    this.getChartData();
  }
  
  getChartData() {
    var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/heart";
    // var response = fetchIntradayDataHR(url);


    console.log(fetchIntradayDataHR(url));
    *// Got undefined here.*


    this.setState({ ... });
  }
  
  
// DataFetch.js
// Helper function to sort out the Browser difference
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

export function fetchIntradayDataHR(url) {
  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if(!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported!');
    return {};
  }

  xhr.onload = function() {
    var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var parsedObj = renderIntradayData(parsedResponse);


    console.log(parsedObj);
    // Got the correct result here tho...


    return parsedObj;
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Error making the request!');
    return {};
  };

  xhr.send();
}

// ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`fetchIntradayDataHR` is an asynchronous function . Then , you need to pass a callback to be running when the response comes .

So, the first change is the signature of fetch function :

```
export function fetchIntradayDataHR(url, onSuccess, onLoad) {}
```

instead of

```
export function fetchIntradayDataHR(url) {}
```

Then in the React Component, you will call this function accordingly and **the callback will includes `this.setState`** :

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/heart";

const onSuccess = (response) => this.setState({ok : true}); 
const onError = (error, response) => this.setState({ok: false}); 
fetchIntradayDataHR(url, onSuccess, onError);
```

instead of

```
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/heart";
// var response = fetchIntradayDataHR(url);


console.log(fetchIntradayDataHR(url));

this.setState({ ... });
```

---

Brief you code can as the following :

```js
// App.js
import {
  fetchIntradayDataHR,
  fetchDailyLogHR
} from './DataFetch';

// ...
componentWillMount() {
  // Called the first time when the component is loaded right before the component is added to the page
  this.getChartData();
}

getChartData() {
  const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8080/heart";
  // var response = fetchIntradayDataHR(url);
  const onSuccess = (data) => this.setState({data: data, fetching: false});  //!--- ⚠️ ATTENTION
  const onError = (error) => this.setState({message: error, fetching: false});  //!--- ⚠️ ATTENTION
  this.setState({fetching: true}); // start fetching
  fetchIntradayDataHR(url, onSuccess, onError);  //!--- ⚠️ ATTENTION
  console.log(fetchIntradayDataHR(url)); * // Got undefined here.*


  this.setState({...
  });
}


// DataFetch.js
// Helper function to sort out the Browser difference
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);
  } else {
    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    xhr = null;
  }
  return xhr;
}

export function fetchIntradayDataHR(url, onSuccess, onError) {
  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported!');
    return {};
  }

  xhr.onload = function() {
    var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    var parsedObj = renderIntradayData(parsedResponse);
     

    console.log(parsedObj);
    // Got the correct result here tho...
    onSuccess(parsedObj); //!--- ⚠️ ATTENTION

    return parsedObj;
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    onError('Error making the request!');  //!--- ⚠️ ATTENTION
    return {};
  };

  xhr.send();
}

// ...
```

Comment: Thx man! It works now. Although the chart doesn't get plotted after the setState() in react...still need to look into the other part...

Comment: You are Welcome @TommyTang